# How does the play/pause button on the keyboard work?

Tags: browser, keyboard-events

My computer keyboard, like many modern ones, has a button to play/pause music. It works with many applications, like the Spotify native player, Google Music web player, ITunes, etc. Some of these are native, and some are in a browser. The button works even when the program (or browser tab) is not in focus. How do these programs hook into this functionality?

I expect that it works somewhat as follows, but this is just a guess:

1. Web app registers a sound channel with the browser, providing some callbacks for pause/play/stop, etc.
2. Browser registers its sound channel with the OS, providing some callback functions
3. Pause button is pressed on keyboard
4. OS calls a callback for the registered sound channel
5. Browser's native callback calls the web app's Javascript callback function, which executes the pause

(And for native applications, the indirection through the browser would be skipped)

Answer (score 3):

I'll guess you mean Windows. The answer is more or less the same across operating systems, I'll point out Windows-specific references here.

They are not as special as you seem to think they are. They are standard keyboard keys, and even [have constants in the Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) (look for `VK_MEDIA_`, `VK_LAUNCH_`, `VK_BROWSER_`, etc).

The keyboard hardware sends sends scan codes for those keys to the operating system just like normal keys.

Programs can listen for keyboard events globally using a Windows hook with [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) (see `WH_KEYBOARD`).

Browsers may or may not expose those keys. Browsers can send `keydown` and `keyup` events to elements with raw scan codes, so there is no reason why it is not possible to detect them in a web page. A windows hook may filter out those keys, so they may not reach the browser process. You can try it by pressing one of those keys with your cursor in the "Try It!" field, on [this page](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Comment: Oh my goodness, you're right it's so much simpler than I was imagining :) Thank you!